# $.ajax() call not working as I would like it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

So I make this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/videos",
   data: { title: oembed.title }
});
```

inside this function call to the Embedly API:

```
$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:300,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){ 
});
```

Now there's two things wrong with the way this $.ajax() call is working. First, it's being calling every time I load the `index` view, which makes sense because that's where I'm pointing the url. However, I want it to be called just once when the video is created, and I don't know how to point it to just the `create` method.

Second, the ajax call is just adding an empty row to the database, and the title, which is generated dynamically by the embedly API and stored in the `oembed` hash (the selector finds the video link in my view and turns it into an embedded video, as well as stores all of the video's attributes in `oembed`), is not being inserted into my database. I'm trying to store this dynamically generated title into my database.

How do I accomplish both of these goals?

UPDATE: If you're curious and want to see this in action, fork the code here: https://github.com/meltzerj/Dreamstill

UPDATE 2: Here's what the console says. Note that one is for `create` and the other is for `show`:

Started POST "/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Mar 16 03:03:12 -0700 2011
  Processing by VideosController#create as 
  Parameters: {"title"=>"Exclusive: Charlie Sheen Says He's 'Not Bipolar but 'Bi-Winning' (02.28.11)"}
  AREL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "videos" ("description", "thumbnail_url", "released", "video_url", "user_id", "title", "embed_code", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-03-16 10:03:12.277518', '2011-03-16 10:03:12.277518')
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/videos/413
Completed 302 Found in 17ms

Started GET "/videos/396" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Mar 16 03:03:03 -0700 2011
  Processing by VideosController#show as 
  Parameters: {"id"=>"396"}
  Video Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."id" = 396 LIMIT 1
Rendered videos/_show_video.html.erb (6.4ms)
Rendered videos/show.html.erb within layouts/application (9.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 33ms (Views: 24.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the correct data? What does your console tell you? And if you're creating stuff, why go to index? You should be pointing it to new(/videos/new) if you're doing it RESTfully.

Comment: also, please paste the parameters you get when you submit the data should look somethingl ike this Started POST "/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-16 15:51:20 +0800
  Processing by YourController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"title"=>"whatever"}

Comment: I posted it, and it has the title as a parameter, but it's not being inserted into the db. If I point the url to `/videos/new` I get a routes error, although I have the `new` controller and view...

Comment: whats in your routes then? also /videos as create is not RESTful. try to fix your routes first. also, how are you saving your video? your parameters should not be like that, it should be something like { :video => {:title => "whatever"} } etc

Comment: checked your stuff and all seem okay. what happens when you go to videos/new? you still need to fix your data though

Comment: when I point the ajax call to /videos/new, I get this error: Started POST "/videos/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Mar 16 04:51:57 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/videos/new"):

Comment: What do you mean fix my data? Also I'm able to go to `/videos/new`, but for some reason there's a routing error when the ajax is called on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your code and ran it. I didn't face the routes issue you described, but I am running Rails 3.0.0. I don't know if that is making a difference or not.

Anyway, your `application.js` file is running exactly the way it's coded to. Basically what is happening is:

On the index page, each video link is of the form `<a href="some_video" class="oembed">some text</a>`

The Javascript in application.js is trying to convert all `oembed` classed links to embedded videos. In doing so, once it succeeeds, it runs the AJAX POST, which is really not what you want.

What I'd recommend is:

- In your Add Window `#dialog`, (modal partial I believe), change the form to a remote form.
- Write a javascript view `create.js.erb` and include some JS that uses the Embedly API to get the title of the video based on the URL. The method currently in use - binding the `embedly-oembed` method is probably not the best way to do it. The API probably has a specific way of getting the title without having to convert a hyperlink to an embed.
- Remove the AJAX call from the `application.js` 's  `embedly-oembed` event binding, since you don't want to create something each time it converts a link to an embed.
- If the API doesn't have a method like this, you could probably do something along the lines of: Submit Video -> Use `create.js.erb` to generate a link in the modal partial, and then uses the existing method along with an AJAX call (called only for this window), which does an UPDATE through PUT (not a CREATE through POST) to update the title of the video it just added to the database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here are the embedly docs: https://github.com/embedly/embedly-jquery/blob/master/README.rst Do you see any methods for retrieving the title?

Comment: Yes, the very first line under Call Directly: 

`#Alert the tile of a video
$.embedly('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfamTmY5REw', {}, function(oembed, dict){
   alert(oembed.title);
});`

Instead of alert, you would use your AJAX call.

Comment: Ok this is a noob question, but since the video url is supplied by the user, how would I pass it to the embedly call? Also, if this is just for the create controller, how do the index and show views know to display the videos there? Originally I had the embedly call in my application.js file find the links in my index and show views by the CSS selector and replace it with the corresponding video and thumbnail. How would I be able to do this with this different type of embedly call that only lives in the create.js.erb file?

Comment: I've also noticed that finding the links and replacing them with videos takes forever, so this new embedly call would probably speed things up and make it more pleasant for the user.

Comment: You can just do something like: 
`<%= @video.url %>` (don't have access to your code right now, but basically, use embedded ruby to reference the URL using embedded ruby) in your .js.erb where you need to supply the url. As for the index and show views, they can stay as-is, I would simply remove the ajax call from your `application.js`, now that you're already taking care of it in `create.js.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

your new call should be GET if you're using resources :videos. check your rake routes.

as for the data, it should be in the form:

```
Parameters: {"video"=>{"title"=>"Exclusive: Charlie Sheen Says He's 'Not Bipolar but 'Bi-Winning' (02.28.11)"}}
```

NOT

```
Parameters: {"title"=>"Exclusive: Charlie Sheen Says He's 'Not Bipolar but 'Bi-Winning' (02.28.11)"}
```

so basically, data should look like this:

```
data: { video: {title: oembed.title} }
```